# Can re-booting when it's trying to install the OS cause damage?

Tags: windows-8

Recently, my computer was slowing down so I decided to reinstall Windows 8. I'm happy to lose all my data on there as it's already backed up.

First I tried to refresh it, then it said there were some errors with the refresh (without telling me what type of errors) and it tried to undo the change and then it showed this "attempting repairs" screen.

But this screen was stuck there for 2-3 hours. I wasn't sure whether it was "attempting repairs" or if it was stuck.

Anyway, after a while, I decided it was hanging and rebooted. And it showed up with this error code 0xc0000001 which at [this site](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/4677/t/19510683.aspx) says it means that I need to use the original disks to repair it.

So I stuck the disk in and so far, I've tried to

- refresh the OS
- reset the OS
- reinstall Windows 8 again, deleting all the previous partitions
- automatically repair the OS (which it fails to do)
- do a bios diagnostic check on the hardware (which returns no problems)
- reset my BIOS settings
- Made sure SATA mode is ATCI
- use two windows install disks (one on USB and one on DVD)

It's taken hours, I still just get that same error. I can't even get into safe mode.

So if it's not a hardware issue, and I've deleted and formatted the previous partitions before re-installing the OS, what could be some possible things that could be causing the system to not boot up? What lingers after I delete all the partitions on my hard drive?

Could I have somehow damaged the firmware when I rebooted as it was attempting repairs?

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting during an installation process will do nothing more than leave a partial (and therefore, corrupt) installation. It can't damage hardware, and certainly can't damage firmware. Windows installation doesn't touch device firmware.

What I notice in your list is that you deleted the partitions and reinstalled Windows as two separate steps. I would delete the partitions, **then** do a clean install rather than messing around with refreshing and startup repair.

You do in fact have to use the OEM discs to reinstall Windows unless you have a retail copy.

Comment: How do I delete the partition seperately? The only way I'm deleting the partition is when I boot from the Windows 8 DVD, during the install process it asks me which partition to install from and I just delete all the existing partitions before installing it onto a new one.

Comment: I don't have the OEM discs because I upgraded to Windows 8 from Windows 7. The copy of Windows 8 I'm using is one I downloaded off the Microsoft site and I have a seperate Windows 8 key that allows me to install Windows 8 not as an upgrade.